# Upload multiple pictures to SQL Server database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to upload multiple pictures to a SQL Server database by using Entity Framework.

I have successfully uploaded one picture to the database before but I need to upload multiple pictures one time.

I tried to take the pictures as `ICollection<IFormFile> Pic` in the DtoModel and convert them to byte[] in the primary model to store them in the database but it didn't work and I just stored one picture in the database from many I have uploaded.

primary model:

```
public class property
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Photo is required.")]
    public byte[] Pic { get; set; }

    public string PicFromat { get; set; }
}
```

DtoModel:

```
public class dtoprop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IFormFile> Pic { get; set; }

    public string PicFromat { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private new List<string> _allowedExtenstions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".png" }; 
private long _maxAllowedPosterSize = 1048576;

public propertiesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( dtoprop model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View( model);
        }

        if(!_allowedExtenstions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(model.Pics.FileName.ToLower())))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Pic", "Only .PNG, .JPG images are allowed!");
    
            return View(model);
        }
    
        if (model.Pics.Length > _maxAllowedPosterSize)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Pic", "Poster cannot be more than 1 MB!");
            return View(model);
        }

        using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();

        await model.Pics.CopyToAsync(dataStream);

   using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] conv = null;


            if (model.Pic != null )
            {
                // Loop thru each selected file
                foreach (IFormFile photo in model.Pic)
                {
                    await photo.CopyToAsync(dataStream);

                     conv = dataStream.ToArray();

                }
            }


        var pic = new property
        {
            Name = model.Name,
             Pic = conv,
            PicFromat = model.PicFromat
        };

        _context.Properties.Add(pic);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So, do I need to create a new image model with a one-to-many relationship with the primary model? or there is a better way can implement this approach without store the images in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: You seems to be appending all the file bytes to one stream. You need to create one `_context.Properties.Add(pic);` for each `IFormFile`....

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can you make an answer with your suggestion, please ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing binaries inside your DB tables instead of in mass-storage somewhere? Storing images in an RDBMS will introduce a bottleneck and introduce other issues (hence why MS recently added `FILESTREAM`, but it's hardly a panacea), so generally it's best to _not_ store files in a database.

Comment: Looks like you need to add inside the loop, also ensure you instanstiate the variable each time for the byte array and not append like what has been suggested.  Another option to explore is taking the InputStream directly and this should already have a list of bytearrays which you could use.  I think they used to call it InputStream, but this has been changed in .net core.

Comment: @Dai I am aware of that, I want to know this approach

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your controller code block as follows:

```
if (model.Pic != null )
{
    // Loop thru each selected file
    foreach (IFormFile photo in model.Pic)
    {
        var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
        await photo.CopyToAsync(dataStream);

        byte[] conv = dataStream.ToArray();

        var pic = new property()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Pic = conv,
            PicFromat = model.PicFromat
        };

        _context.Properties.Add(pic);
    }
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for me, with this if I want to add a new object "Pic" with multiple images it will add every image as a new object so for example I if add a new "Pic" with the Name "test1" and upload three images for "test1" it will store 3 different images with the same name "test1", but what I want to be able to add 3 or 4 images for same  'Pic_id' at the same time

Comment: provide more details about your question so that your issue can be replicated

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you need to consider for such approach i.e.

Make sure that the underlying database e.g. in case of SQL server must have data type as **VARBINARY(MAX)**. this will store the byte array data in a single row.

Seeing your code I can tell that **you actually needs multi-row List<byte[]> data type to store the multiple images bytes** inside a single row of table.

Since you are just using the datatype byte[] it means that in your **foreach loop** the last image you convert to byte array will be stored in your variable, meaning in your **conv** variable you are storing the bytes of single image not multiple images.

Know that any database infrastructure does not allows to store list of anything even byte array in a single row, **you eventually need to use one to may database relation to store the list of multiple files byte array in a multiple rows separately**.

You may have found some hack, but it eventually runs to data type max limits as either your number of images increases or your image size increases.

In short, you need one to many relation mapping model to store multiple images even in bytes in the database, you can not store multiple images byte array in a single row by design. I hope I am able to clarify few things here.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try to implement it ASAP, but I want to know in your opinion what's the best approach to store/upload multiple images for a single object or in my case 
 the same "property_id" and where can I find the source to learn it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to create a separate table for the Image Name "test1" and the unique ID (primary key) which will be used to locate the collection of images uploaded to separate table.

Upload would require two writes, one to the table that stores the "ImageName" and unique key and second write to upload the images individually with a column linking them back to the "ImageName".